# Error: Call to a member function connection() on null + new composer package

Tags: php, laravel, connection

I am creating new composer PHP package. and I ran into error "Error: Call to a member function connection() on null"
I was trying to connect to database using "use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;". here is my capsule code

```
<?php

namespace APN;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

trait DB
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule;
        $capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => DBDRIVER,
            'host' => DBHOST,
            'database' => DBNAME,
            'username' => DBUSER,
            'password' => DBPASS,
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
        ]);
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();
        $capsule->bootEloquent();
    }
}
```

?>

```
<?php

namespace APN\Order\Portal;
use APN\Models\ToolsNBNRestLocation;
use APN\Models\ToolsNBNCSA;

/**
 * OrderAPI
 */
class OrderAPI
{
    use DB;
    public function productOrderQualification() {
        print_r(ToolsNBNCSA::all())
    }
}
```

when I run the unit test it throws "Error: Call to a member function connection() on null" at line print_r(ToolsNBNCSA::all()).
any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried to utilize DB trait inside a class, but was not able to read database

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The given code does not call `connection`  anywhere

Comment: actually me too can't see any where the connection() method. What the fact is that similar code is working on my other git branch. I was not able to fix the issue. what I want to say again, I need to have database connection on my newly creating PHP Composer package. Docker is used here in my case. I am trying to have Eloquent mode to read db table

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error messages and your attempts to resolve the problem. It could help if you also shared the code calling the given code, in an example that triggers the error message

Comment: <?php
namespace APN\AppointmentAPI\Portal;
use APN\Models\ToolsNBNCSA;
class AppointmentAPI { 
     use DB;
   public function test() { 
         print_r(ToolsNBNCSA::all()) 
   }
 } but its not retrieving db table data.

Comment: "Error: Call to a member function connection()" on null is the error message

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Please share more details. What does `ToolsNBNCSA::all()` do?

Comment: ToolsNBNCSA::all() shall return all records in my Tools_NBN_CSA mysql table

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**. Also, share more details about how the connection happens. You still haven't shared the full and exact error message, and the line that triggers that error

Comment: hey thanks for your time. I found the solution that models should contain DB capsule like use DB; should be there in as first statement of ToolsNBNCSA class. as follows

<?php
namespace APN\Models;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use APN\DB;
class ToolsNBNCSA extends Model
{
    use DB;

    protected $table = 'Tools_NBN_CSAS';
}